# In Mat table Not able to specify height of the table and make the header as well as footer sticky

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular8

I have a Mat table with Header and beneath the table I have added a paginator component , I have adjusted paginator component to be as a footer seen in both the images.

*Now the question is I want Rows to be scrollable with the tables Header and Footer(i.e Paginator Component) to be fixed at one place.*

But Currently As shown in the second Image if **I select the 10 rows** then the height of the table increases and I get the Scroll on the main Div.

Tried hard for hours but wasn't able to do it I will put the Exact Code which I have Written so that It can be better ShowCased.

Below is my **html file**

```
<div class="outerDiv">
<div class="table-container">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Id </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Mobile Number </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.phone}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns;sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="paginator">
  <mat-paginator [length]="2"
  [pageSize]="5"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]">
</mat-paginator>
</div>

</div>
```

Below is My **css file**

```
.mat-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}
  
  th.mat-sort-header-sorted {
    color: black;
  }

  .table-container{
    margin-top: 10px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto
  }
 

  .outerDiv{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 226px;
    padding-top: 67px;
    padding-bottom: 67px;
  }

  .paginator{
    margin-right: 155px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 80%;
    position: sticky;
  }
```

[image: the table with 5 rows]

Now the table with 10 rows

[image: Here the table is with 10 rows]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i told earlier Scroll is coming on div because there is a table in that div as well as top-bottom paddding of (30+30) px in vertical direction as you can see in image below.

[image]

**we can remove this problem by 2 solution**

1. use margin instead of padding as we know margin are spaces outside any div not inside but in this situation it will work same as padding space.

   .example-container {
   height: 300px;
   overflow: auto;
   margin:30px
   }

please look into image below for result of above code.

[image]

2. second way to fix this problem is make another div outside `example-container` and add padding to that while over `example-container` will wrap the table. see the stackblitz code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-72dlr3-cehygm)

Comment: Yes Thanks for the answer I Did the same thing But just one thing I would request you can you add mat-elevation-z8 class to paginator component as well as table I tried to apply it but as soon as I select the items per page 10 than the table elevation is slight more that brings the table up kindly add the mat-elevation-z8 class in the paginator as well as table and check it.

Comment: Please help me with the elevator class by adding in the table as well as the table the table rises above the paginator component while chosen 10 as Items per page

Comment: apply it on outer div i have updated stackblitz example in this asnwer

Comment: great this answer will work for sure for any beginners as this is the most tricky question ever in material design and this could be the simplier and effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a purely css problem. For making header sticky add sticky to `mat-header-row`

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"> 
</tr>
```

To make paginator sticky wrap table in a div and put paginator outside that div (make sure to add `mat-elevation-z0` class to table so there is no shadow between table and paginator or add custom shadow class in table and paginator).

I have made a updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-72dlr3-y5umat) for you (please view in full size screen).

Comment: the Style Didn't work As I checked different css for hours and the stackBlitz example Dosen't satify the sticky header as well as the Sticky footer..!!

Comment: There are two scrolls see clearly on the outer div and footer dosent seems to be sticky

Comment: I just updated my Question As I am now closer to the answer I just wrapped the table inside the div called table-container and also updated the css file I think you can copy my css classes and can update the html and css files in your stackBlitz to see the where theres mistake..!!

Comment: can you create a stackblitz of your current code so i can debug.

Comment: sure let me check

Comment: Let me copy your example and set my elements in it would be easier then

Comment: I copied the example same as you did it worked but by applying few styles it went wrong firstly observe that as we increase page size to 10 the elevation of the table div increases and just apply padding:30px to the example container div and then do page size to 10 the scroll comes to outer div instead of table thanks for the cooperation

Comment: please upvote and accept answer so this will help others also who will come here with same problem.

Comment: umm ya sure I will but as you read in the comments It didnt help me completely for checking you can apply padding 30 px to the example-container class in your stackBlitz and try increasing page size you will see the UI breaking as well as the scroll is applied to the outer div not the table

Comment: my answer was general for problem so it will help all with same problem.if still you are facing some problem with your other project's css please add a stackblitz example would be happy to help you

Comment: the problem can be reproduce in your stackBlitz example also just add padding:30px to your stackBlitz Example and make items per page 10 by clicking from UI and see the results the scroll is on the outer div not the table and secondly the elevation of the table rises up then the pagination component.

Comment: there is no need for me to provide the stackBlitz example just put the padding in your example and run the example then select 10 in items per page

Comment: can you use margin(30px) in place of padding ? as i can see padding is creating empty place inside.

Comment: still the problem occurs apply margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px; to .example-container class and give style to paginator component and apply only left and right margin as 30 px the reason I dont know why it dosent work but still this is the simple issue that we arent able to solve.

Comment: just let me know if you find any full proof solution as Its basics only and there is no special case that I have but will upvote for your hard work but if you need your answer to be approved please provide solution by checking..!!

Comment: I just answered this question but dont worry will not approve that one you can have a look still something is missing in my answer and I have provided a stackBlitz Url hope you can crack it so that I can approve your answer  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out the solution based on @shashank sharma solution

But still its half on the way...!! Didnt got success

Below is the link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-72dlr3-needdq

I just answered this as the next one who is answering dosent have to look through the entire conversation but will not approve this or edit this..!!

problem is

1. the same example is being provided everywhere but the scroll comes to the div containing the table but not the table itself
2. The sticky header and footers arent working quite well..!!
3. the content gets scrolled up over the header..!!